# display a tooltip on a disabled button and remove it if it is enabled using AngularJS on one button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code: The tooltip shows only when its enabled. I need it to invert.

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrapper disabled" data-title="testing" uib-tooltip="TESTing" tooltip-enable="disabledBtn">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="clickDelete()" ng-model="disabledBtn" ng-disabled="!disabledBtn" ng-style="{'pointer-events':!disabledBtn ? 'none' : ''}">Delete</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* display: block works as well */
  margin: 50px; /* make some space so the tooltip is visible */
}enter code here

.tooltip-wrapper .btn[disabled] {
  /* don't let button block mouse events from reaching wrapper */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(function () {
      $('.tooltip-wrapper').tooltip({ position: "bottom" });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `tooltip-enable="!disabledBtn"` to enable tooltip when *disabledBtn* value is *false*.